# In ONO 99, what is the rule for a player holding 3 99's and a -10, when the new total would be negative?

Tags: untagged

There is seemingly no rule in the ONO 99 rule book to cover this case. It is your turn to play, and you hold three 99's and a -10, and the total on the pile is less than 10. Are you eliminated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original 1980s game, there is no need to address the situation because it follows the rules exactly.

The player cannot play any of the 99 cards, because this is disallowed by the rules, and they cannot discard the hand to replace it, because they are only holding three 99 cards, not four.

They are not eliminated because they can play a card that will not take the pile's total above 99, because a negative number is always less than 99, so that is what they must do.

Then they draw another card, and the game continues.

In the 2022 game version, the pile's total cannot go below zero. The player is unable to play an acceptable card, therefore they are eliminated.

Comment: When playing the 2022 printed version, the rules say "the pile's cannot go below zero", but there are 2 valid ways to interpret that: "You cannot play a card that would make the pile go below zero" or "if the sum would go below zero, it stays at zero instead". The second interpretation would allow you to play the -10 card. Are those rules clear on which it is?

Comment: Nothing beyond that simple expression. But based on the presence of two places they could have specified that it's locked at zero-or-more, rather than just starting there and not allowed lower, and that this is a game advertised as suitable for children below the usual age of learning about negatives, and that the game is meant to be short and is based on player elimination, I'd say pragmatically if not technically, it's "you can't play, you go out".

Answer (score 2):

No, you are not eliminated.

Update: Mattel's customer service rep confirms that the rules are not explicit on how to handle this case but declines to resolve the rules, with the usual manufacturer-of-games-made-for-children appeal to "you can play the way you want to make it fun for you" boilerplate (ignoring those of us who find that "fun" means playing by the official rules).

Quote from Mattel email:

> there is going to be time to time when you and your players make the game more unique and decide how the experience is going to play out.
>
> In this case scenario where the count is 5 and it is Bob's turn and he holds three 99s and a Minus Ten, then what does Bob do? Well, the rules are simple, he can't make the count go below 0 so the -10 won't do, [he can't] put down the three 99s because he needs four to actually do it.
>
> You can decide how your game is going to work in this type of case, let say for example you decide any -10 used when the count is below ten actually makes de count go down to zero, if you abide by this rule then Bob would be able to use -10 card and set the game on 0.
>
> Another option would be to make Bob pass, you would skip his turn because he has actually a completely useless hand at the moment.

(Of particular note: the rep uses "skip" and "at the moment" rather than "is eliminated", leaving "Bob" free to play again the next round, assuming the count rises to 10 or more -- according to the rep, this is not one of the ways to be eliminated from the game)

My original answer continues, which matches the "clamp to zero" option from the rep (or the original rules, if you're using those):

You can play the minus ten. You are only prohibited from playing the 99s (the prohibition is against bringing the total to 99 or more).

You can play the Minus 10. This will bring the total to negative (or to zero in the 2021/2022 version -- in the new version, the count never drops below zero, even if a -10 would bring it to the negatives).

[Original](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/349599/ono-99-rules):

> There is no restriction on when you can play the Minus Ten card.

> Note: A minus 10 card may be played if the total is 0, then making the total a minus 10.

[New version](https://www.geekyhobbies.com/how-to-play-ono-99-card-game-rules-and-instructions/):

> When you play the -10 card, you will subtract ten from the current total. The discard pile total can never go below zero.

> Note: In the 1980s version of the game, you can make the total go below zero and into the negatives.

You're not out, even in the new version, unless "you are unable to play any card in your hand without causing the total to hit or
exceed 99", and playing a -10 doesn't meet that criteria.

[New Rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/HHL37-Eng.pdf):

> ### ONO 99 IN A NUTSHELL
>
> If you are unable to play a card without making the total hit 99 or above, you are out of the game.

and

> ### On Your Turn
>
> If you are unable to play any card in your hand without causing the total to hit or exceed 99, you’re out – DON’T PLAY ANY CARD!

No other mechanism for being eliminated is given in the rules.

Conjecture: in addition to simplifying the rules from the standpoint of not dealing with negative numbers, this also removes the contradiction that the 99 cards "cannot be played" when it seems like they could be played if the count were negative. In my opinion, that latter issue is the most likely reason for changing the rules to disallow the count from dipping into the negative range.

Rules:

> The bad news: if you are dealt or draw an ONO 99 card, you must keep it and you may not play it.

Comment: The rules I have say, for the -10 card: "The -10 card subtracts 10 from the pile. Negative totals are not allowed." seems to be a 2021 version, based on the copyright statement.

Comment: @Benjamin Ah, thanks. Maybe the "2022" rules Eric Mortensen is using are actually the 2021 rules (or the rules in the 2022 printing were actually set in 2021). But both allow the the Minus Ten to be played; they only clamp the lower bound of the count to zero: if the count falls into the negatives, it is instead clamped to zero.